# CMake avoid copying Qt5 Dlls on windows

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I'm using Qt and CMake to develop C++ applications.
On linux there my qt application runs fine, however on windows i have to copy the folders
C:\Qt\5.15.8\msvc2019_64\bin
and
C:\Qt\5.15.8\msvc2019_64\plugins
to the binary folder.

If I do not copy these files to the binary folder I'm getting Qt5xxx.dll missing at application startup.
However (especially when using CMake Multi Config generators) this is a pretty waste of HDD space (and time).
Is there any way to avoid this (this issue seams to be windows only)
I'm running the example taken from https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.12/cmake-manual.html

I also did try to set the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH before find_package()

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:/Qt/5.15.8/msvc2019_64/bin")
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS ${ACTIVE_QT_MODULES} REQUIRED)
```

but this does not seam to work. Is there any other way to get this to work?

Thx for your help :)

**Edit**
To clarify: I'm looking for a solution for a developer PC. All developer PCs already have multiple Qt versions installed at C:/Qt. Therefore in my opinion the copying on developer PCs is not necessary. Of course, when deploying the application to a non developer PC we use the deployqt tool to copy all the necessary stuff

Comment: If you get this message on your dev machine you should add your C:\Qt\5.15.8\msvc2019_64\bin to PATH. For deployment to end user machine copying dlls is necessary and the best way to do it on windows is to use windeployqt tool bundled with Qt

Comment: hey thx for your answer. I added some clarification. We only want to avoid the copying on developer PCs. I added C:\Qt\5.15.8\msvc2019_64\bin
to the Path directly in windows and via CMakePresets `"environment": {
        "PATH": "$penv{PATH} C:/Qt/5.15.8/msvc2019_64/bin"
      }`.
But none did work. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: You need to add the base dir of the QT platform installation to the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`, e.g. `C:/Qt/5.15.8/msvc2019_64`. The default separator for windows `PATH` variable is `;` not space. So your environment entry should read `$penv{PATH};C:/Qt/5.15.8/msvc2019_64/bin`

Comment: For Visual Studio setting some additional target and directory properties come handy: `set_property(DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} PROPERTY VS_STARTUP_PROJECT <executbale_target>)` and `set_property(TARGET <executable_target> PROPERTY VS_DEBUGGER_ENVIRONMENT "PATH=C:/Qt/5.15.8/msvc2019_64/bin")` See [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/search.html?q=VS_DEBUGGER) for a list of `VS_DEBUGGER` properties

Comment: @vre Thx replacing the SPACE with ";" and adding this to my Preset `"environment": {
        "PATH": "$penv{PATH};C:/Qt/5.15.8/msvc2019_64/bin"
      }` worked. However to Qt version to choose is config depended and setting this within a qt.cmake file 
  `set(ENV{PATH} "$ENV{PATH};C:/Qt/5.15.8/msvc2019_64/bin")` did not work. Do you have an idea how to set the path from within a *.cmake file. (I did add the Target properties as suggested)

Comment: That's why I mentioned the `VS_DEBUGGER_ENVIRONMENT` variable in the second comment. You can set that from inside a CMake file. It is not only meant for debugging purposes but in general for modifying the runtime environment for applications started from your solution (also in Release config). You don't need to repeat the PATH var in there, the environment is merged.

Comment: Hey thx, It took me some time to figure out the problem. If I open a generated VS2022 solution file the VS_DEBUGGER_ENVIRONMENT property works nicely. However when opening the same project as a CMake (Preset) Project in VS2022 DLLs are still not found. I believe this property is tied to the generated Solution.
=>so the question is can I set the PATH Variable somehow within CMake `set(ENV{PATH} "$ENV{PATH};C:/Qt/5.15.8/msvc2019_64/bin")` did not work

Comment: Setting the `PATH` variable from inside CMakeLists.txt will only change the environment of the currently executing CMake configuration process. If you later build your generated solution with Visual Studio or Ninja this environment does not inherit the variable definition. AFAIK there is no way to set an environment variable in the calling console process from a CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: thx @vre for all your help. If someone has the same issue, I did summarise the output of our discussion in a separate answer

Answer (score 1):

Use CMake to find the necessary directories (dynamically), and generate two outputs.  The first is, as recommended by @vre, VS_DEBUGGER_ENVIRONMENT for execution from the debugger and via the IDE.  The second is a batch file that sets the environment variables, then invokes the process.

```cmake
# Get location of Qt DLLS from the bin dir
get_filename_component(QT_BIN_DIR ${QT_MOC_EXECUTABLE} DIRECTORY)

# Also find the location of the Qt plugins, using a random plugin
get_target_property(qsqlite_loc Qt5::QSQLiteDriverPlugin LOCATION_Release)
get_filename_component(Qt5SqlDriver_PLUGIN_DIR ${qsqlite_loc} DIRECTORY)
get_filename_component(Qt5_PLUGINS_DIR ${Qt5SqlDriver_PLUGIN_DIR} DIRECTORY)

# Tell VSCode about these paths so the debugger can launch the app
string( CONCAT debugger_environment
  "PATH=${QT_BIN_DIR};%PATH%\n"
  "QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=${Qt5_PLUGINS_DIR}/platforms\n"
  "QT_PLUGIN_PATH=${Qt5_PLUGINS_DIR}\n"
  )
set_property(TARGET mytarget PROPERTY VS_DEBUGGER_ENVIRONMENT ${USERFILE_ENVIRONMENT})

# Also make a batch file
string( CONCAT batch_contents
  "set PATH=${QT_BIN_DIR};%PATH%\n"
  "set QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=${Qt5_PLUGINS_DIR}/platforms\n"
  "set QT_PLUGIN_PATH=${Qt5_PLUGINS_DIR}\n"
  "$<TARGET_FILE_NAME:${mytarget}>"
  )
file( GENERATE OUTPUT "$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:mytarget>/$<TARGET_FILE_BASE_NAME:${mytarget}>.bat"
  CONTENT "${batch_contents}" )
```

Variation: Omit the call to the target executable, and instead allow the .bat file to be called from a terminal to set up future runs from that terminal.

Future improvements: handle UNIX shell syntax for non-Windows builds

Answer (score 0):

This post is just for summarising the comments section.
After lots of input from @vre it turns out that there are 2 ways to solve this issue

1. add C:/Qt/5.15.8/msvc2019_64/bin to your PATH.
   =>Problem here: It is not easy to select a specific QT Version across different projects depending on a project configuration
2. add

`set_property(DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} PROPERTY VS_STARTUP_PROJECT <executbale_target>)`

and

```
set_property(TARGET <executable_target> PROPERTY VS_DEBUGGER_ENVIRONMENT "PATH=C:/Qt/5.15.8/msvc2019_64/bin")
```

=>Problem here: You select different Qt Versions for different projects. However the executable only starts when the (generated) solution file is used to run the executable

Comment: `VS_STARTUP_PROJECT` does nothing on generators besides Visual Studio, yet Ninja and Ninja Multi-Config are increasingly popular on Windows (and well supported by first-party tools, like VS Code).